# Rails 4 Generating application wide dynamic nav-bar links

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I am trying to generate links in my nav-bar based on records. 
I want to post a link in the patrols section of my app that correspond to a patrol route that an admin generated?

I have tried to place

`@patrol_routes = PatrolRoute.all` in the application controller

and then i want something like

```
<% @patrol_routes.each do |patrol_route| %>
 <%= link_to patrol_route.name, patrol_route_path %> so that it takes me to the show page of the patrol route i want to access? 
<% end %>
```

Is this possible? i have tried to google and research it, but I'm not finding anything, perhaps I'm not hitting the correct key words?

Comment: what are you looking for?

Comment: I want to take records that are generated In my patrol routes model and create links to them in the nav  bar

Comment: your above code is working?

Comment: no its not working

Comment: what error are you facing?

Comment: ill plug the code back in and get back to ya, it was crashing out the app so i removed it

Comment: can you give me error log?

Comment: did you write `before_filter` action in application controller?

Comment: no i did not create a before filter.. ill try it.. just need to finish off the block in creating now and ill get it back to where i was

Comment: did you get solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have a route (as in config/routes.rb) named patrol_route you should do:

```
<% @patrol_routes.each do |patrol_route| %>
 <%= link_to patrol_route.name, patrol_route_path(patrol_route) %>
<% end %>
```